# Beginner javascript, Showing previous number in an array and resetting a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I'm really new to javascript and I've challenged myself to make a really basic bingo number machine. https://codepen.io/ryantinsley/pen/LdOvgL I have generated an array of 20 numbers, shuffled them numbers and I add a marker to the board every time one is drawn. I have a two part question which I know is really easy for some of you guys, but its driving me insane.

Part 1
I have added a reset button which takes the squares that are marked red and removes the classes. What I want to do however which I haven't managed to figure out is I want to reshuffle my array every time the reset button is pressed also.

Part 2
As part of increasing the functionality of this display I have also added a previous number section which shows the last picked number. I have managed to make it work to some degree although I am positive there is a better way to do it. Im also struggling to hide the 'undefined' input that is always shown at the beginning. but I'm sure there is a way to do this were I wouldn't need to hide an undefined class anyway

Thanks for all your help in advance, you're amazing.

P.s. I'm just looking to work in pure javascript at the moment.

```js
// This bit shuffles an array

function shuffle(array) {
    var i = array.length,
        j = 0,
        temp;
        
    while (i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));

        // swap randomly chosen element with current element
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}

// Array input

var ranNums = shuffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]);

//This bit calls the position of the array
var f = 0;
var g = -1;
// the index of the current item to show

function nextNumber() {
  var randNum = ranNums[f++];
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = randNum; 
    
    if (f == ranNums.length) f = 0;   // reset to first element if you've reached the end
  
    document.getElementById("item" + randNum).className = "red";
}

function lastNumber() {
  var past = ranNums[g++];
    document.getElementById('previous').innerHTML = past;
  
  if(past === "undefined") {
    document.getElementById('previous').style.display='none';
  }
}






 // Removes the class and resets the game
function resetNumbers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranNums.length; i++) {
       document.getElementById("item" + ranNums[i]).className = "";
      
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


h1, th {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman",Times, serif;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
}


table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 30px;
  float: left;
}


th, td {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}

h2 {
  
}

button {
  
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bingo!</h1>
<h4>Current Number</h4>
<h2 id="current"></h2>
<h4>Previous Number</h4>
<h2 id="previous"></h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="item1"<h1>1</h1></td>
    <td id="item2"<h1>2</h1></td>
    <td id="item3"<h1>3</h1></td>
    <td id="item4"<h1>4</h1></td>
    <td id="item5"<h1>5</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="item6"<h1>6</h1></td>
    <td id="item7"<h1>7</h1></td>
    <td id="item8"<h1>8</h1></td>
    <td id="item9"<h1>9</h1></td>
    <td id="item10"<h1>10</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="item11"<h1>11</h1></td>
    <td id="item12"<h1>12</h1></td>
    <td id="item13"<h1>13</h1></td>
    <td id="item14"<h1>14</h1></td>
    <td id="item15"<h1>15</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="item16"<h1>16</h1></td>
    <td id="item17"<h1>17</h1></td>
    <td id="item18"<h1>18</h1></td>
    <td id="item19"<h1>19</h1></td>
    <td id="item20"<h1>20</h1></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<button onclick="nextNumber(); lastNumber();">Next Number</button>

<button onclick="resetNumbers()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Your numbers are not randomized on the boxes when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the previous number field is defined or not, and only display a value if it is:

```
document.getElementById('previous').innerHTML = past ? past : '';
```

This is using the ternary operator, and does the same thing as this:

```
if (past) {//check if past is not null or undefined
  document.getElementById('previous').innerHTML = past;
else {
  document.getElementById('previous').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Modified code pen: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqEdmY)

Answer (score 1):

For the undefined issue, you're checking undefined as a string. Undefined is simply undefined, so

```
if(past === "undefined") {
    document.getElementById('previous').style.display='none';
}
```

Should be

```
if(past === undefined) {
    document.getElementById('previous').style.display='none';
}
```

For the reshuffle problem, you've already got the `shuffle` function, and you've got the shuffled numbers stored in the `ranNums` variable, so you can simply run an array of numbers through the `shuffle` function again and assign them to the `ranNums` variable when you call reset, so

```
// Removes the class and resets the game
function resetNumbers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranNums.length; i++) {
       document.getElementById("item" + ranNums[i]).className = "";

    }

  ranNums = shuffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]);
}
```

Now, this is a rather basic way of answering your questions, so I'm going to suggest a few other improvements:

1. Keep your array of numbers to shuffle in a variable so you don't have to repeat it in the reset function.
2. Remove the number from Current Number when the reset button is pressed.
3. If you haven't already, read up on the differences between `==` and `===`, you're using both in different `if` statements.
4. Read up about JavaScript objects and try and contain all your code in an object so you don't pollute the global namespace (this isn't really an issue with what you're doing at the moment, but it's a good habit to get into).

Other than that, good job, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do these 2 things:

- part 1: Use a new array that will contain 2 numbers, current and previous and update the array as you select the new number. no need to go through the loops for that simple check.
- use the ranNums array to generate HTML table from it and then when you shuffle your array of numbers, you can re-generate the HTML table.

I just gave you an idea to achieve it in a better way. Let me know if you want some more clarification on something. Thanks